How to make itext support Cambodian, Thai, Arabic
I have a JAVA WEB system that requires PDF to create artwork, but the user told me that the text tested in Thai, Cambodian, and Arabic is incorrect. Our system kernel, itext4, may have added content that was previously needed for development. How can I improve it?
Can I simply change it to itext7-8? But I didn't succeed in testing with itext8


Can you give me some tips on how to modify it? Thank you!

It's an add-on: https://itextpdf.com/blog/technical-notes/displaying-text-different-languages-single-pdf-document

Please don't post images of code.
